# "find -ls" with proper time-style

Tags: linux, bash, find, datetime-format, ls

i use the following command to generate a filelist which i compare sometimes to see if something is changed:

```
find /directory -xdev -ls
```

My Problem is that the time in the output is not always in the same format:

```
Sep 19 08:48 ./pool/f/f/0/ff046cc5b7188073cbd68207c52bddc5
Nov  2 06:24 ./pool/f/f/0/ff0e803c36d89315a6b3663ed1295f71
Jan 18  2012 ./pool/f/f/0/ff07f60465d8deb7a1aa38096d0b798d
Jan 18  2012 ./pool/f/f/0/ff07436f519bddf1d340afde5a240375
```

For the ls-command there is the option --time-format=long-iso to force the same time-format for all files. 
Is it possible to combinate this with the find-command?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing in my manpage about changing the format of the  `-ls` parameter. In fact, on my system, the output of `-ls` is not influenced by various environment variables that affect the output of the `ls` command itself. I assume that the format of the `-ls` parameter is internal to `find` and does not involve the actual `ls` command. To me, this makes programming sense. Why run an external command? Just simulate the display.

The only way I can think of to get around this is to use `-exec` or `-print0` to pass the results to the actual `ls` command. A bit of warning: If you pass the name of the directory, `ls` will print the contents of that directory, so you'll need to pass `-d` to the `ls` command or add `-type f` into your `find` query. I checked the manpage for find on Linux, and found that it's suppose to be the same output as `-dils`, so I used that. Since `-d` is included, I didn't have to add `type -f` to my find query:

This is using the `-exec` which will send each and every file or directory individually to the `ls` command. If you have 10,000 files, `ls` will be called 10,000 times.

```
$ find /directory -xdev -exec ls -dils --time-style=long-iso {} \;
```

This maybe more efficient:

```
$ find /directory -xdev -print0 | xargs -0 ls -dils --time-style=long-iso
```

This will group as many file names as possible that will fit into the command buffer and pass them at once to the `ls` command. It will call the `ls` command as many times as needed to complete all of the files. For example, if you have 10,000 files in your `find` command, the `ls` command will be called maybe once or twice instead of 10,000 times.

The problem is that `xargs` has issues with funny file names, and there are some security issues as pointed out in the manpage:

> It  is  not possible for xargs to be used securely, since there will always be a time gap between the production of the list of input files and their use in the commands  that  xargs  issues.   If  other users  have access to the system, they can manipulate the filesystem during this time window to force the action of the commands xargs runs to apply to files that you didn’t intend.  For a more  detailed discussion  of  this and related problems, please refer to the ‘‘Security Considerations’’ chapter in the findutils Texinfo documentation.  The -execdir option of find can often be used as a more  secure alternative.

The `-print0` parameter uses a `NUL` character to separate out file names instead of a `NL` and the `-0` parameter tells `xargs` to use the `NUL` character as a file name separator rather than *whitespace* (the characters in the `$IFS` environment variable).

This means using `-print0  | xags -0` works almost all of the time, but you may still decide that `-exec ls` is a better way to go.

Comment: xargs doesn't have issues with "funny file names" when used with -0.

Another way to use ls efficiently is to use -exec ... +.   Regarding security, the point you quoted above only makes a difference if there is a security-relevant implication to whether and how a file turns up in the output of the -ls or ls.

Answer (score 12):

You can use various options to -printf  (man find)

```
find . -printf "%CY-%Cm-%Cd %CH:%CM\n"
```

Comment: Dang. I forgot about `-printf` on GNU's version of `find`. There's no `-printf` parameter on other Unix systems, so it's not universal. On my Mac, `-printf` does not exist. However, if the OP is using `--time-style` in `ls`, he's has the GNU tools, and `-printf` should work.

Comment: FWIW -printf cannot simulate the x -> y notation that ls uses for symlinks.

Comment: Note: `%C` gives you the `ctime`, which will not match the datetime that you get from `ls -l`, which is `mtime`. If you want to get the same `mtime` that matches `ls -l`, use `%T` instead of `%C`.